# My object literally move once per frame and it is not moving smoothly, I called this up from another script

Tags: unity, c#

Script A

```
    [SerializeField] GameObject BackgroundUPS;
     void Awake()
        {
            BackgroundUPS = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Upper");
    
        }

if (SecondsBetweenSpawn <= 0.7f)
            {
                FirstSpawn.SetActive(false);
                SecondSpawn.SetActive(true);
                BackgroundUPS.GetComponent<GoUp>().FloatingUp();
            }
```

Script B

```
public void FloatingUp()
{
    transform.Translate(Vector2.up * floatUp * Time.deltaTime);
    if (transform.position.y >= 4.29f)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 4.29f);
    }

}
```

Guys sorry but why does my object literally moves up one per frame and so not smooth-like. I want it to move smoothly in Script A. The movement of the object is from Script B. But i called it from Script A, just fyi. Pls advice?

Comment: Whats the value of `floatUp`? Do you expect your Script A to run smoothly or is Script B not rnning smoothly? The condition in SCript A is in `Update()`?

Comment: Do you have a rigid body or collider component on the object that's moving up?

Comment: I think you mistyped in your FloatingUp().. Instead of transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, 4.29f);. It needs to be transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.y, 4.29f);